# Threejs - Raycaster with direction parallel but offset by 3 from line reports true for intersectObject

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to use a THREE.Raycaster to determine if a line will intersect with my ray, but when comparing with parallel line the intersectObject method is returning true.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
var rc = new THREE.Raycaster(new THREE.Vector3(500,0,0), new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), 0, 100);
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();
var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
    new THREE.Vector3(0,0,3),
    new THREE.Vector3(1000,0,3)
]);
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices = spline.getPoints(1);
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
if (rc.intersectObject(line)) {
    var found = document.createElement('div');
    found.innerHTML = 'detected intersection, but why?';
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(found);
}
```

the above code displays:

```
detected intersection, but why?
```

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4phen0xe/)

Comment: Nice find. `THREE.Ray.distanceSqToSegment()` is buggy. It is returning `NaN`s in your example. Would you be willing to file a three.js bug report? See "How to report a bug" in the [guidelines](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: sure thing, I'll file it right away

Comment: issue filed: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a ray and a line segement parallel to that ray should not intersect. :-)

This bug has now been fixed in the three.js development branch r.70dev.

three.js r.70dev